# Windows Authentication IIS 6 IsAuthenticated is always false

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, iis-6, windows-authentication

I have ASP web site using Windows Authentication.

Here are the web.config settings

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

When I host the website in IIS 6 the user never gets authenticated so Request.IsAuthenticated is always null in Application_AuthenticateRequest method. Same about the identity of the CurrentPrincipal.

The weird thing is that when I switch the website to use Visual Studio Dev Server, everything works brilliantly.

I have Integrated Windows Authentication ticked in the IIS web directory settings.

What am I doing wrong? Any help or advise will by much appreciated.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, using a proxy server?

Comment: @Taleeb Nope. I'm testing the application locally. As I said the windows authentication works with Visual Studio Development Server, but not with IIS.